# Why isn't Destination not allowed when you use the Link parameter in the Worksheet.Paste method

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I can't find a logical reason for this restriction. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx

I need to copy/paste Links, so I need to Specify Link:=True, but due to the restriction, I can't.

Now I am stuck with selecting the cell and then Paste without the destination argument, but what if I want to do it on a hidden sheet? It seems silly to have to unhide the sheet, select the destination cell, paste, and then rehide the sheet, and then reselect the sheet and cell that was selected before to restore state.

Comment: Lets see the code you are referring to.

Comment: Just use code to put linking formulas in the relevant cells. You don't *have* to use Copy at all for this.

Comment: Sure I don't. But I'm doing this for an area, not a single cell. It just seems a lot cleaner if I could just copy and paste links. It's not that I don't have a workaround (now that you mentioned, the R1C1 formula seems to be reasonably clean since all of the cells in the region would have the same formula), but I'm trying to find a logical reason for the restriction and hopefully a cleaner solution.

Comment: What makes you think there's a logical reason? After all, the `Destination` argument doesn't have to be on the same sheet whose `Paste` method you're using - how logical is that?

Answer (score 0):

If I had sheet3 hidden this code will still work.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Range("A3:D3").Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

The example in your link, well... it's just an example.

Comment: I made edits in the question to clarify that I want to use Link:=True